# Append path url to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl

I had initially defined perl variables

```
$delimit ="C";
$filename=\\aemdata.fcc.com\aem\GE\2015\Files\list.txt
```

I used to use those perl variables in javascript. whenever user clicks on save, the above variables would be passed through ajax and backend perl subroutine would be executed based on these above paramters.  Here is that code.

```
var form_data = new FormData();

form_data.append('action', "File_Check"); //perl subroutine which is called 
form_data.append('delimit', "$delimit");
form_data.append('jsondata', data);

\$.ajax({
    url: http://aemdata.fcc.com/cgi-bin/test/excel.pl, // directed to url where that perl subroutine is placed
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'post',
    data: form_data,
    cache:false,
    datatype: "script",
    success: function (result) {

    },

    error: function (data) {

    }   
});
```

This code worked fine. Now instead of specifying the $filename initially at the start. I want to dynamically add it as a parameter. Append it to the javascript object and pass it along with other parameters to the subroutine perl code. Here is the second code where i get the error

```
var form_data = new FormData();

form_data.append('action', "File_Check"); //perl subroutine which is called 
form_data.append('delimit', "$delimit");
form_data.append('jsondata', data);
form_data.append('filename', "$filename"); //ERROR ON THIS LINE


\$.ajax({
    url: http://aemdata.fcc.com/cgi-bin/test/excel.pl, // directed to url where that perl subroutine is placed
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'post',
    data: form_data,
    cache:false,
    datatype: "script",
    success: function (result) {

    },

    error: function (data) {

    }   
});
```

This append doesnt work. it gives me a error like "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL" on 5th line of above code. 
If i could pass this along with other paramters, the subroutine would be called and the code would run fine. however i am unable to pass the URL using append.

Can Someone please suggest anything over here ? any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant section of Perl code, the JavaScript code that *isn't* working, and the *exact* text of the error you're getting, including line number.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot- updated the post with the details. can you please have a look now

Comment: Are you outputting this JavaScript code from Perl? If so, why the separate AJAX request? Why not just build the entire page using Perl?

Comment: @MattJacob- Hi, good to see you. The entire page is build using Perl. i have added javascript inside of it.

Comment: I understand that, but why? You're making a separate HTTP request and adding complexity when you probably don't need to. Anyway, to answer your original question...

What does the _source_ of the generated page look like for the line with the error? Those backslashes will need to be escaped properly for a JavaScript string.

Comment: @MattJacob- from your comment, i understand that the syntax error is probably because the backslashes are not properly understood by javascript string. how could i change the code to achieve that ?

Comment: @MattJacob- if i use \\ instead of \ and \\\\ instead of \\, the $filename works. i guess this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As matt mentioned above, the following changes to the code worked. As soon as i get the dynamic path, i use regex and then append it to the javascript object.

The code is as follows:

```
$filename=~ s/\\/\\\\/g;
form_data.append('filename', "$filename");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your resultant string contains backslashes, which are escape characters in JavaScript. You'll need to handle any special characters using the proper [escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation), e.g., `\\` instead of `\` for a backslash.